# Is it possible to start a video playing in a tooltip in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video

In Silverlight a tooltip can have as many elements in it as you want.

However, it doesn't receive focus so you can't have user interactivity in it.

Could you, though, start a video playing as soon as the tooltip opens and have the video stop as soon as the tooltip closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first answer on Stack Overflow so I ask for your good humor.
I think you could run your video in the tooltip by using a video brush.

Here's some code I used to paint a fire video on the bar in the chart that represented heating with corn.  ( long story)  right here, you can see it is set to the fill of an ellipse.

```
 #region video brush setup
       protected void setupVideo()
       {
           VideoBrush _vb;
           MediaElement mevideo;

           _vb = new VideoBrush();
           mevideo = new MediaElement();
           mevideo.SetValue(Grid.NameProperty, "video");
           Uri videoUri = new Uri("http://www.faxt.com/videos/ezburnboilerfire.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);
           mevideo.Source = videoUri;
           mevideo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           mevideo.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(me_MediaEnded);

           MediaRoot.Children.Add(mevideo);
           _vb.SetSource(mevideo);

           Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
           el.Width = 100;
           el.Height = 100;
           el.Fill = _vb;
           MediaRoot.Children.Add(el);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a VideoBrush as suggested by BPerreault, but you could also just set Tooltip.Content to a MediaElement.

That is because the Content property of Tooltip inherits from ContentControl and the Content property of a ContentControl can be any type of object, such as a string, a UIElement, or a DateTime. When Content is set to a UIElement (like MediaElement), the UIElement is displayed in the ContentControl. When Content is set to another type of object, a string representation of the object is displayed in the ContentControl. ([from documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(VS.95).aspx))

It should be something like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="MouseOver and you'll get a ToolTip!">
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <MediaElement x:Name="myVideo" Source="Butterfly.wmv" Width="300" Height="300" />
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock >
```